# Pipenv installationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in

Tags: python, django, installation, pipenv

I have recently moved over to using pipenv and every now and then I get the following error when trying to install packages:

**$ pipenv lock --clear --verbose**

```
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
```

**$ pipenv install social-auth-core**

```
 line 704, in from_line
line, extras = _strip_extras(line)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**$ python setup.py egg_info**

```
(k, v) for k, v in attrs.items()
File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-app-VE-name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 367, in __init__ 
for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'iter_entry_points'
```

The github pages for the error have not been helpful, thank you

Comment: Have you activate your env?

Comment: yes I have @Walucas

Answer (score 7):

I think these may be bugs that have been fixed in the latest pipenv. Are you using the latest versions of pipenv (and pip, setuptools, and wheel)?

Assuming you're using `--user` installs, you can upgrade and/or check with the following command:

```
$ pip install --user --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager pipenv wheel
Requirement already up-to-date: pipenv in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2018.11.26)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.32.3)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools>=36.2.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv) (40.6.3)
Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv) (16.1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv) (0.4.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip>=9.0.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv) (18.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv) (2018.11.29)
```

**Note:** This should be run *outside* of your virtual environment, not while it's activated.

Comment: Thank you Pi, I now get: _from pkg_resources import Requirement
ImportError: cannot import name 'Requirement'_

Comment: This worked, I had messed up my ve. So running the above command and then recreating my ve. Thank you Pi!

Comment: DID not work at 1st, until I killed my ssh & re-ssh in. Then it magically worked. What duh? Anyway. Thank u!

Comment: @user6273920: That may be because of a stale PATH cache entry for "pip", if the upgrade changed the effective path. If you're using bash, you can explicitly refresh the cache with "hash -r".