# Virtualenvwrapper: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'iter_entry_points'

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Every time I open a new shell, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 132, in main
    run_hooks(hook, options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 161, in run_hooks
    hook_mgr = ExtensionManager(namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 106, in __init__
    verify_requirements)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 179, in _load_plugins
    for ep in self.list_entry_points():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 168, in list_entry_points
    eps = list(pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(self.namespace))
AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'iter_entry_points'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.5 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Oddly enough, `virtualenvwrapper` is still working fine. If I try to activate a virtualenv, it spits out this error again, but the environment does load up. This was after I recently tried to clean up my Python versions on my Mac, but I clearly messed up some path.

Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipenv installationError: Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1 in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780525/pipenv-installationerror-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27pkg_resources%27+has+no+attribute+%27iter_entry_points%27